# Placing a TextBox on top of a header column in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following function that responds to the ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick event in a DataGridView:

```
void grid_ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    //make the new textbox the same size as the header to cover it up until text is entered
    t.Width = ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.ContentBounds.Width;
    t.Height = ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.ContentBounds.Height;
    t.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    t.Visible = true;
    t.BringToFront();
    t.Text = "TEST";
    Controls.Add(t);
}
```

All of this code is happening inside of a class that extends Panel and had a DataGridView added to the controls of the panel. When I double click on a header and put a breakpoint on this handler the handler is called, but I don't see the textbox anywhere. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making the textbox a class field (declare it outside the event trigger so it doesn't go out of scope by the end of it).  Might have to set the coordinates for the textBox as well :). Don't have VS on this machine to try this out but I hope this will help.